# Jquery change/focus/blur overrides submit in Firefox

Tags: jquery, forms, focus, submit

A form with a single textfield is given. A submit handler is bound on the form and a change/focus/blur handler bound on the textfield.

When something is entered into the textfield and the submit button is then clicked, only the change/focus/blur event is registered in Firefox, while in Safari, both are registered.

The form:

```
<form id="form1" action="" method="get">
<input id="text1" name="text1" type="text" />
<input id="submit1" name="submit1" type="submit" />
</form>
```

The Jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#text1').change(function(){ alert("1"); });
 $('#form1').submit(function(){ alert("2"); });
});
```

In Firefox: "1" is alerted.
In Safari, "1" is alerted, then "2" is alerted.

How can I get the behaviour in Safari to work in Firefox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here looks like it is caused by the `alert`.

If you run the code without the `alert` or change it to `console.log` the code behaves as you expect, with both the change and submit events being fired.

```
$(function() {

  $('#text1').change(function() {
    console.log("change");
  });

  $('#form1').submit(function() {
    console.log("submit");
    return false;
  });
});
```

Since you don't ever want to use `alert` in production code, you should be able to get the result to want without any changes.